# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping, entitymanager

I generate the entities from database, it's raise a lot errors in mapping
In my code this is 2 entities where one contains a composite key, I try to do the mapping but the error

> "Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:"

is raised, This is the code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mib_traps", schema = "public", catalog = "pfeDb")
@IdClass(MibTrapsEntityPK.class)
public class MibTrapsEntity {
    private String module;
    private String nomTrap;
    private int valTrap;
    private String enterpriseTrap;
    private String enterpriseOid;
    private MibsEntity mibsByModule;


    private Collection<MibVarbindsEntity> mibVarbinds;

    @Id
     @Column(name = "module", nullable = false, length = 100)
     public String getModule() {
     return module;
    }

    public void setModule(String module) {
       this.module = module;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "nom_trap", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getNomTrap() {
       return nomTrap;
   }

    public void setNomTrap(String nomTrap) {
       this.nomTrap = nomTrap;
     }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "val_trap", nullable = false)
   public int getValTrap() {
        return valTrap;
   }

    public void setValTrap(int valTrap) {
        this.valTrap = valTrap;
    }

   @Basic
    @Column(name = "enterprise_trap", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getEnterpriseTrap() {
       return enterpriseTrap;
   }

    public void setEnterpriseTrap(String enterpriseTrap) {
       this.enterpriseTrap = enterpriseTrap;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "enterprise_oid", nullable = false, length = 500)
   public String getEnterpriseOid() {
                 return enterpriseOid;
    }

       public void setEnterpriseOid(String enterpriseOid) {
        this.enterpriseOid = enterpriseOid;
    }
 
       @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
              if (this == o) return true;
           if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
          MibTrapsEntity that = (MibTrapsEntity) o;
              return valTrap == that.valTrap &&
            Objects.equals(module, that.module) &&
            Objects.equals(nomTrap, that.nomTrap) &&
            Objects.equals(enterpriseTrap, that.enterpriseTrap) &&
            Objects.equals(enterpriseOid, that.enterpriseOid);
    }

    @Override
      public int hashCode() {
       return Objects.hash(module, nomTrap, valTrap, enterpriseTrap, 
      enterpriseOid);
      }

   public MibsEntity getMibsByModule() {
      return mibsByModule;
     }

       public void setMibsByModule(MibsEntity mibsByModule) {
         this.mibsByModule = mibsByModule;
     }


      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mib_traps_by_mib_varbinds_module_trap_fkey")
          public Collection<MibVarbindsEntity> getMibVarbinds() {
        return mibVarbinds;
      }

      public void setMibVarbinds(Collection<MibVarbindsEntity> 
     mibVarbinds) {
         this.mibVarbinds = mibVarbinds;
     }
     }
```

this is the second entity:

```
 @Entity
   @Table(name = "mib_varbinds", schema = "public", catalog = "pfeDb")
    public class MibVarbindsEntity {
       private String moduleTrap;
  private String nomTrap;
   private Integer indexVb;
    private String moduleVar;
    private String varTrap;


    private MibTrapsEntity mib_traps_by_mib_varbinds_module_trap_fkey;

      @Id
    @Column(name = "module_trap", nullable = true, length = 100)
    public String getModuleTrap() {
    return moduleTrap;
    }

   public void setModuleTrap(String moduleTrap) {
    this.moduleTrap = moduleTrap;
        }

    @Basic
  @Column(name = "nom_trap", nullable = true, length = 100)
   public String getNomTrap() {
      return nomTrap;
   }

 public void setNomTrap(String nomTrap) {
         this.nomTrap = nomTrap;
     }

     @Basic
      @Column(name = "index_vb", nullable = true)
       public Integer getIndexVb() {
    return indexVb;
    }

    public void setIndexVb(Integer indexVb) {
    this.indexVb = indexVb;
   }

  @Basic
   @Column(name = "module_var", nullable = true, length = 100)
   public String getModuleVar() {
      return moduleVar;
   }

     public void setModuleVar(String moduleVar) {
     this.moduleVar = moduleVar;
      }

       @Basic
            @Column(name = "var_trap", nullable = true, length = 500)
     public String getVarTrap() {
    return varTrap;
   }

  public void setVarTrap(String varTrap) {
         this.varTrap = varTrap;
    }

    @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if (this == o) return true;
     if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
       MibVarbindsEntity that = (MibVarbindsEntity) o;
      return Objects.equals(moduleTrap, that.moduleTrap) &&
            Objects.equals(nomTrap, that.nomTrap) &&
            Objects.equals(indexVb, that.indexVb) &&
            Objects.equals(moduleVar, that.moduleVar) &&
            Objects.equals(varTrap, that.varTrap);
     }

      @Override
    public int hashCode() {
     return Objects.hash(moduleTrap, nomTrap, indexVb, moduleVar, 
    varTrap);
      }


          @ManyToOne
          @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "module", insertable = false, updatable = 
            false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "nom_trap", insertable = false, updatable = 
       false)})
       public MibTrapsEntity getMibTrapsByMibVarbindsModuleTrapFkey() {
         return mib_traps_by_mib_varbinds_module_trap_fkey;
       }

         public void setMibTrapsByMibVarbindsModuleTrapFkey(MibTrapsEntity 
        mibTrapsByMibVarbindsModuleTrapFkey)
   {
    this.mib_traps_by_mib_varbinds_module_trap_fkey = 
  mibTrapsByMibVarbindsModuleTrapFkey;
}
}
```

Comment: Does it work when you change `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mib_traps_by_mib_varbinds_module_trap_fkey")` to `@OneToMany(mappedBy ="mibTrapsByMibVarbindsModuleTrapFkey")`?

Comment: @crizzis I think it work, but another error it's raised, there is any solution for that? I generate entities from database and I have 100 table

Comment: We won't be able to tell you if there's any solution until you tell us what that 'another error' is

Comment: I solved the error of mapping manually, but when I test the web service I got this error: "{"cause":null,"message":"Could not resolve repository metadata for CatalogueEntities."} ( I have a class named CatalogueEntity

Comment: That error is coming from spring-data-rest. Please ask a separate question, detailing your rest repository configuration

Comment: @crizzis I have a old version of postgresql, I tried to generate entities in intellij from the database postgresql but it's raise errors of mapping ( for exemple the error at the top)